# Substitute first character before match

Tags: regex, perl, csv, substitution

For each line I need to add a semicolon exactly one character before the first match of an alphanumeric sign but only for the alphanumeric sign after the first appearance of a semicolon.

Example:

Input:

```
00000001;Root;;
00000002;  Documents;;
00000003;    oracle-advanced_plsql.zip;file;
00000004;  Public;;
00000005;  backup;;
00000006;    20110323-JM-F.7z.001;file;
00000007;    20110426-JM-F.7z.001;file;
00000008;    20110603-JM-F.7z.001;file;
00000009;    20110701-JM-F-via-summer_school;;
00000010;      20110701-JM-F-via-summer_school.7z.001;file;
```

Desired output:

```
00000001;;Root;;
00000002;  ;Documents;;
00000003;    ;oracle-advanced_plsql.zip;file;
00000004;  ;Public;;
00000005;  ;backup;;
00000006;    ;20110323-JM-F.7z.001;file;
00000007;    ;20110426-JM-F.7z.001;file;
00000008;    ;20110603-JM-F.7z.001;file;
00000009;    ;20110701-JM-F-via-summer_school;;
00000010;      ;20110701-JM-F-via-summer_school.7z.001;file;
```

Could someone helps me please to create Perl regex for that? I'd need it in a program, not as a oneliner.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your own attempts. That makes it easier for us to tell you where you went wrong and how to fix it. Also, do you have the entire input in one string, or do you read it line by line?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to create a regex, that fits my requirements. I know basic regular expressions and tried to get more knowledge about it. Yet, the tutorials are very verbose (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). My only idea was, to index every line like this 

while ( $result != -1 ) {
        $offset = $result + 1;
        $result = index( $string, $char, $offset );
    }


and to check, when the white spaces end. I read the input line by line using an array. But that's no regular expression anymore.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here is a program that seems to match your requirements:

```
#/usr/bin/perl -w
while(<>) {                                                           
  s/^(.*?;.*?)(\w)/$1;$2/;                                            
  print $_;                                                           
}
```

Store it in a file 'program.pl', make it executable with 'chmod u+x program.pl' and run it on your input data like this:

```
program.pl input-data.txt
```

Here is an explanation of the regular expression:

```
s/        # start search-and-replace regexp
  ^       # start at the beginning of this line
  (       # save the matched characters until ')' in $1
    .*?;  # go forward until finding the first semicolon
    .*?   # go forward until finding... (to be continued below)
  )
  (       # save the matched characters until ')' in $2
    \w    # ... the next alphanumeric character.
  )
/         # continue with the replace part
  $1;$2   # write all characters found above, but insert a ; before $2
/         # finish the search-and-replace regexp.
```

Based on your sample input, I would use a more specific regular expression:

```
s/^(\d*; *)(\w)/$1;$2/;
```

This expression starts at the beginning of the line, skips over numbers (\d*) followed by the first semicolon and space.  Before the following word character, it inserts a semicolon.

Take what fits best to your needs!

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to insert a semi-colon after the first semi-colon and whitespace, but before the first non-whitespace.

```
s/;\s*\K(?=\S)/;/
```

If you feel the need, you can use `\w` instead of `\S`, but I felt with this input it was an unnecessary specification.

The `\K` (keep) escape is similar to a lookbehind assertion in that it does not remove what it matches. The same goes for the lookahead assertion, so all this substitution does is insert a semi-colon in the designated spot.

Comment: Note that this works only if the input is read line-by-line. Otherwise, you'd add `^[^;]*` to the beginning of the pattern, and the `mg` modifiers.

Comment: @m.buettner No, you cannot just add `^`, you'd need to insert `^[^;]*` or some such. But since we can choose to not complicate things, it is better to choose not to do so.

Comment: Wow, did you peek over my shoulder when I wrote my comment? :P

Comment: `s/;\s*\K(?=\S)/;/` can be simplified to `s/;\s*\K/;/` if there's no lines consisting entirely of `00000009;`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for your really great answers!
Actually my code snippet looks like this:

```
 our $seperator=";" # at the beginning of the file
 #...
 sub insert {
    my ( $seperator, $line, @all_lines, $count, @all_out );
    $count     = 0;
    @all_lines = read_file($filename);

    foreach $line (@all_lines) {
        $count = sprintf( "%08d", $count );
        chomp $line;
        $line =~ s/\:/$seperator/;                          # works
        $line =~ s/\ file/file/;                            # works

        #$line=~s/;\s*\K(?=\S)/;/;                          # doesn't work
        $line =~ s/^(.*?$seperator.*?)(\w)/$1$seperator$2/; # doesn't work
        say $count . $seperator . $line . $seperator; 

        $count++; # btw, is there maybe a hidden index variable in a foreach-loop I could us instead of a new variable??
        push( @all_out, $count . $seperator . $line . $seperator . "\n" );
    }

    write_file( $csvfile, @all_out ); # using File::Slurp
}
```

In order to get the input which I presented you, I made already some small substitutions, as you can see in the beginning of the foreach-loop.
I am curious, why the regular expressions presented by TLP and Yaakov do not work in my code. In general **they work**, but only when written like in the example which Yaakov gave:

```
while(<>) {                                                           
  s/^(.*?;.*?)(\w)/$1;$2/;                                            
  print $_;                                                           
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that when you say my($seperator,...) at the beginning of the insert() function, you hide the declaration our $seperator=";" from the top of the file.  Remove the variable $seperator from the list my($seperator...) and try the program again.

Comment: Some general debugging hints: Start your program with the -w switch (e.g. by writing in the first line of the program #!/usr/bin/perl -w).  This will print useful warning messages like for using undefined values.  Also, I strongly suggest to put 'use strict;' at the top of your file.  This will bring up a lot of errors in the compilation phase.

Comment: Was a stupid mistake of myself, I found the error, thank you Yaakov!